# For Comprehension of Futures - Kicking off new thread inside comprehension and disregarding result

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I'm trying to use a for comprehension to both run some futures in order and merged results, but also kick off a separate thread after one of those futures completes and not care about the result (basically used to fire some logging info)

I've played around a bit with this with some thread sleeps and it looks like whatever i'm throwing inside the for block will end up blocking the thread.

```
private def testFunction(): EitherT[Future, Error, Response] =
    for {
      firstRes <- EitherT(client.getFirst())
      secondRes <- EitherT(client.getSecond())
      // Future i want to run on a separate async thread outside the comprehension
      _ = runSomeLogging(secondRes)
      thirdRes <- EitherT(client.getThird(secondRes.value))
    } yield thirdRes

def runSomeLogging(): Future[Either[Error, Response]] =
        Thread.sleep(10000)
        Future.successful(Right(Response("123")))
    }
```

So this above code will wait the 10 seconds before returning the `thirdRes` result. My hope was to kick off the `runSomeLogging` function on a separate thread after the `secondRes` runs. I thought the usage of `=` rather than `<-` would cause that, however it doesn't.

The way I am able to get this to work is below. Basically I run my second future outside of the comprehension and use `.onComplete` on the previous future to only run my logging if certain conditions were meant from the above comprehension.  I only want to run this logging function if the `secondRes` function is successful in my example here.

```
private def runSomeLogging(response: SecondRes) =
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    response.value.onComplete {
      case Success(either) =>
        either.fold(
          _ => {  },
          response => { logThing() }
        )
      case _ =>
    }

private def testFunction(): EitherT[Future, Error, Response] =
        val res = for {
          firstRes <- EitherT(client.getFirst())
          secondRes <- EitherT(client.getSecond())
          thirdRes <- EitherT(client.getThird(secondRes.value))
        } yield thirdRes
runSomeLogging(res)
return res
```

This second example works fine and does what I want, it doesn't block the for comprehension for 10 seconds from returning.  However, because there are dependencies of this running for certain pieces of the comprehension, but not all of them, I was hoping there was a way to kick off the job from within the for comprehension itself but let it run on its own thread and not block the comprehension from completing.

Comment: If you `sleep` outside of a `Future` why do you think it would not block the current thread?

Comment: I'm ok with it blocking the current thread, my goal is to have the thread actually running that Future be a separate thread from the for comprehension.

My log function should be stuck for 10 secs, but I don't want the return of the for comprehension itself to be stuck for 10 secs

Comment: In my second example, the runSomeLogging(res) function does operate on its own thread.  So the testFunction completes within its 1 second and returns, while the other thread was spun off and runs the logging function after sleeping for 10 secs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a function that *starts* the Future but doesn't return it, so the for-comprehension can move on (since Future's `map/flatMap` functions won't continue to the next step until the current Future resolves). To accomplish a "start and forget", you need to use a function that returns immediately, or a Future that resolves immediately.

```scala
// this function will return immediately
def runSomeLogging(res: SomeResult): Unit = {
  // since startLoggingFuture uses Future.apply, calling it will start the Future,
  // but we ignore the actual Future by returning Unit instead
  startLoggingFuture(res)
}

// this function returns a future that takes 10 seconds to resolve
private def startLoggingFuture(res: SomeResult): Future[Unit] = Future {
  // note: please don't actually do Thread.sleep in your Future's thread pool
  Thread.sleep(10000)
  logger.info(s"Got result $res")
}
```

Then you could put e.g.

```scala
_ = runSomeLogging(res)
```

or

```scala
_ <- Future { runSomeLogging(res) }
```

in your for-comprehension.

Note, Cats-Effect and Monix have a nice abstraction for "start but ignore result", with [`io.start.void`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/3.x/cats/effect/IO.html#start:cats.effect.IO%5Bcats.effect.FiberIO%5BA@scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance%5D%5D) and [`task.startAndForget`](https://monix.io/api/3.0/monix/eval/Task.html#startAndForget:monix.eval.Task%5BUnit%5D) respectively. If you were using `IO` or `Task` instead of `Future`, you could use `.start.void` or `.startAndForget` on the logging task.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense.  So we're more or less allowing the function inside the for comprehension to complete and return, "unit" in this case, while that function is spinning off its own Future on its own thread.  I think this will do exactly what I want.

And yes I would never use sleep in real code, it was purely for me to test how these threads were executing and delaying.  I just wanted to confirm my logging function in this example would have no delay or hold over my comprehension returning to its caller.

Comment: It looks like I don't need the function explicitly returning Unit.  If I just have the startLoggingFunction in its own Future `Future {`.  It kicks off its own thread.  I can get rid of the `runSomeLogging` and just call `_ = startLoggingFuture(res)`